# ASP.NET Core MVC Have Files Uploaded to certain categories

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-mvc

I have made the code for upload and download (using relative path) fully. Thing is it only uploads them all in the same list. I want to have a navigation bar so that whenever something is uploaded, there is the option to CHOOSE in which category the file will be uploaded, and then, when displayed , I want it to have displayed in the category that it has been uploaded. For example, I have category 1,2,3 and if I upload something to the 2nd category, the user, when will be on the site, should click on the "2" in the navbar and only THEN will he see the uploaded files to number 2.

```
private FilesViewModel files;
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
          
            return View();
        }
       
        public IActionResult Index1()
        {
            // Get files from the server
            files = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                files.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
            }
            return View(files);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index1(IFormFile[] files)
        {
            // Iterate each files
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                // Get the file name from the browser
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

                // Get file path to be uploaded
                var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", fileName);
                

                




                // Check If file with same name exists and delete it
                if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
                }

                // Create a new local file and copy contents of uploaded file
                using (var localFile = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(filePath)) 
                    using (var uploadedFile = file.OpenReadStream())

                    {
                       



                        uploadedFile.CopyTo(localFile);








                    }
        
            }
            ViewBag.Message = "Files are successfully uploaded";

            // Get files from the server
            var model = new FilesViewModel();
            foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload")))
            {
                model.Files.Add(
                    new FileDetails { Name = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(item), Path = item });
                
            }
            return View(model);
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Download(string filename)
        {
            if (filename == null)
                return Content("filename is not availble");

            var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "upload", filename);

            var memory = new MemoryStream();
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
            {
                await stream.CopyToAsync(memory);
            }
            memory.Position = 0;
            return File(memory, GetContentType(path), Path.GetFileName(path));
        }
        private string GetContentType(string path)
        {
            var types = GetMimeTypes();
            var ext = Path.GetExtension(path).ToLowerInvariant();
            return types[ext];
        }

        private Dictionary<string, string> GetMimeTypes()
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {".txt", "text/plain"},
                {".pdf", "application/pdf"},
                {".doc", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".docx", "application/vnd.ms-word"},
                {".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel"},
                {".xlsx", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"},
                {".png", "image/png"},
                {".jpg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".jpeg", "image/jpeg"},
                {".gif", "image/gif"},
                {".csv", "text/csv"}
            };
        }
```

bleow is the model code:

```
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Path { get; set; }

        public string category { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
    }

    public class FilesViewModel
    {
        public List<FileDetails> Files { get; set; }
            = new List<FileDetails>();
        
    }
```

and here is the index1 page (as of now)

```
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}
@*
    For more information on enabling MVC for empty projects, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=397860
*@
@{
}
@model FileUploadDownload.Models.FilesViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-left">
    <h2 style="margin-bottom:50px">Multiple File Upload</h2>
    @if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
        <!-- In order to post files to server we should use form with post method, also need to add multipart/form-data encoding.
               Otherwise the files will not sent to the server. -->

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</form>
    }
    <!-- To show the success message to the user  -->
    @if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success" style="margin-top:50px">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }

    <p style="margin-top: 50px">List of Files</p>
    <!-- Get all the files from the server -->
    <ul>


        @foreach (var item in Model.Files)
        {

            <li>
                <a asp-action="Download"
                   asp-route-filename="@item.Name">
                    @item.Name
                </a>
                
            </li>
        }
    </ul>

</div>
```

I am very new to asp.net and I can not find the right way to this, any help will be greatly appreciated! In other words, I can NOT (do NOT know) how to route them properly...

Comment: What is the specific problem you are facing now？

Comment: That I am very new to C# and I do now know how routing works at all... For example I want to have the option for the admin that when uploading, he gets to choose to which category to upload and then have the file only be uploaded to that category, so for example when the user comes in he will need to click on that specific category in the navbar to have the uploaded items (to that category) displayed. Sorry for my english